# Infinite loop on try catch java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, try-catch, infinite-loop

I got stuck on infinite loop when all if statement is true

UserRepo class

```
public int update(Users user) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Callable<Integer> updateCallable = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {

                return        sqlite_room_dao.update(user.getId(),user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),user.getPassword2());
            }
        };
        Future<Integer> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(updateCallable);
        return future.get();
    }
```

ViewModel class

```
    public int update(Users users) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException,    TimeoutException {
        logger.LogError(TAG, "Update", logger.jsonConverter(users));
        return userRepo.update(users);
    }
```

MainActivity class

```
  final boolean[] isUpdating = {false};
        UserViewModel userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (!isUpdating[0]) {
                isUpdating[0] = true;

                Users user = new Users(5, "kylo", "14", "14");
                userViewModel.getId(user.getId()).observe(this, users -> {
                    if (users.size() == 1) {
                        logger.LogError(tag, "Checked if exist", "true");
                        try {
                            int result = userViewModel.update(user);
                            if (result > 0) {
                                logger.LogError(tag, "Update", "success");
                            } else {
                                logger.LogError(tag, "Update", "failed");
                            }
                        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally {
                            isUpdating[0] = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        logger.LogError(tag, "Checked if exist", "false");
                        isUpdating[0] = false;
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

I tried to put a Boolean flag to prevent multiple loop. but it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you put the observe function inside button `onclickListener` so when every time you click the button the observe function will be call over again.

You need to put observe outside, just init it 1 time with activity. Then with button onclick call the ViewModel to handle your task and when done post result to observe it in activity again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your if statement inside the btnUpdate click listener may be the cause of the problem. The isUpdating flag is first set to true in the listener. Try this out.

```
btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    if (!isUpdating[0]) {
        isUpdating[0] = true;

        Users user = new Users(5, "kylo", "14", "14");
        userViewModel.getId(user.getId()).observe(this, users -> {
            if (users.size() == 1) {
                logger.LogError(tag, "Checked if exist", "true");
                try {
                    int result = userViewModel.update(user);
                    if (result > 0) {
                        logger.LogError(tag, "Update", "success");
                    } else {
                        logger.LogError(tag, "Update", "failed");
                    }
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                logger.LogError(tag, "Checked if exist", "false");
            }
            isUpdating[0] = false;
        });
    }
});
```